# my_object.save(false) doesn't REALLY skip my Active Record validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have been pulling my hair out troubleshooting this bug I have been having, and I finally discovered what was causing it. I had always been under the impression that when I called

```
@my_model.save(false)
```

That I would be ***skipping*** my ActiveRecord validations. Turns out this is partially true. My objects are saving to the database **DESPITE** my ActiveRecord validation. My problem exists because one of my validations modifies one of the children models during the validation process (This is a scheduling application for a 24 hours location, therefore when lunches are saved, I check them against the day they are saving, AND the next day as well to make sure the user didn't mean "2am" for an overnight shift.

My Question is this: Is there a way to actually skip my validations and move straight to the database? Is this normal ActiveRecord behavior or should I be diving deeper into my validations? Or am I out of luck and need to re-write my validations?

Comment: So you're saying that the validation code is still running, it's just ignoring the result of them, and this is a problem since you modify the model in your validations. I'd use something other than validations to sanitize data.

Comment: Thats exactly it! I am guessing that is my ultimate answer, but I thought I would try my luck to see if I could find another.

Comment: Using validations to post-process your business objects is definitely a smell. Validations are meant to check data, not to modify it. To modify, use the various ActiveRecord life-cycle hooks instead: before/after-save, before/after-create etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to use before_create or another callback to interact with the record prior to saving it to the database rather than trying to do this inside of a validator.

Here is the documentation on ActiveRecord callbacks:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

There is also a guide on using callbacks with some details on how to skip them here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html

Answer (score 12):

> My problem exists because one of my validations modifies one of the children models during the validation process

Fix that, then your problems will go away. Validations should never modify the objects!

Answer (score 5):

I agree, you should use callbacks to interact with records. Validations should never modify objects..

If still you find the need to do it.. use

```
myobject.save_without_validation
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Orion, never use a validation to modify an object, use a callback like after_save instead.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, you need to rethink some things. Validations are for validation. If you disagree please comment and we can see what your theory is.